# Incremental memory usage of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-studio-2.2

I am using Android studio 3.1.3 (latest build as of writing this) with Gradle 3.1.3.

And don't know if it matters or not but I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04

Whenever I start Android studio, it starts with very small memory footprint. (single process named java takes around 1GB of RAM)

Now when I start build process, one more java process starts running taking around 500MB of RAM. Still it's no problem as I have 8GB of RAM.

After using studio for about hour or two (includes number of builds as I test on real device), suddenly computer freezes and there are three java process taking up almost 5GB of RAM (approx 2.3, 1.5 and 1.2 GB each). Those processes will not release memory even if studio is seating idle. I have to exit the studio and restart it to make it go away.

Here is the screenshot of my system monitor windows.

[image]

And below is the description of each process.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is anyone else facing this issue? When I was in Ubuntu 16.04 and old android studio, this was not the problem. Does Ubuntu has to do anything with it?

Comment: I have this exact same problem. At first I thought it could be cause of the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, so I changed to Debian 9.5 but the problem persists.

Comment: Same thing here. I switched back to Ubuntu 16.04 and problem is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried many things from many places from internet but nothing seemed to work.

So I downgraded back to Ubuntu 16.04 and issue is no more happening. Maybe some issue with my setup in 18.04 (which I hardly think might be the reason because I did re-setup from scratch twice and issue still persisted) or might be problem with 18.04 (not blaming!)

Thing is, I did not face problem of ram overflow only in Android studio but IntelliJ and TeamCity setup as well. Somehow many many instances of Java kept running in RAM by OS (sometimes over 10 instances of JVM, couple of which took 2 GB each even after build and everything was finished)

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: It happened to me in 16.04 as well

Comment: Same for me on 20.04 for almost a year now. Lucky it is such a good OS otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Android studio on ubuntu 16.04 LTS version but i never faced this problem! If you have 8 GB of ram i think that you can update your Android Studio version and see if there is some improvement.

Anyway you can do something: 
1 - try to use "invalidate cache and restart" function from file or pressing `ctrl + shift + a` or double pressing shift and writing "invalidate cache and restart".
2 - Go in ../yourAndroidStudioInstallationPath and try to delete the hidden folder named ".android".
3 - In your project under gradle script open gradle.properties and uncomment the line `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmxx something`

I have i5 3th u version, 8 GB ram and ubuntu 16.04 LTS and no problem with latest version of studio.

Comment: I am on latest android studio version. Invalidate cache and restart does not help. Let me try with uncommenting the jvmargs line in gradle properties.

Comment: Try to delete .android folder too, this will remove your user settings. And try to refer this official video from android developers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TENdS9Qqcc . Check in your plugins try, try to disable spellchecker and plugins that you don't need. This will release a little bit of memory too!